# p:dataList filter displayed twice on mobile

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I want to use`p:dataList` in my mobile application. The problem is that filter is displayed twice and I don't know why.

This is my view code:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="busListDialog" header="Choose bus">
    <h:form>
        <p:dataList value="#{ztmController.carriageList}" var="item">
            <f:attribute name="filter" value="true" />
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.vehicleNumber}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataList>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

and this is how does'it look like after rendering:

[image: p:dataList]

Any help? Where is the problem?

These are my maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-mobile</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see I use primefaces mobile 0.9.4 and primefaces 3.5.

BTW. I haven't found if it is possible to limit rows per page in primefaces mobile 0.9.4? Is it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's a bug for this version (0.9.4). I tested the same code tor 1.0-SNAPSHOT version ant it works fine.